# Moving two layers at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, layers, spatial-adjustment

I'm trying to move two digitized layers, one containing points, the other polygons to a different location at the same time. QGIS doens't seem to allow this. Even if I select both layers and features it will only move one (the one I last selected, so which ever feature is shown in editor)

I know ArcGIS allows multiple layers to be moved at once, just with the moving tool or with the spatial adjusment. I haven't been able to reproduce this in QGIS.

Comment: AFAIK QGIS does not support editing of multiple layers for now.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same task with polygons' and points' layers (most of points are snapped to polygons, so I have to be precise). 
[image: 01]
I assume, the best way to solve this task is by transfering all layers to the polygon type:

1. Create a special field in both (or more) layers which would help you to recognize which layer each feature is from. Make sure your 'polygon' layer has all the fields which are in others (in my case 'points') layers. It prevents you to lose data.
2. Create buffer around your 'points' layer.
3. Copy created objects to the 'polygons' layer. You have to make sure you can recognize "external" features. In my case, they have the code '1'.[image: codes]
4. Move all the items.[image: moving]
5. Select features from your 'polygons' layer, which has the appropriate layer code (in my case '1').
6. Create centroids from selected features.
7. Replace your points from 'points' layer with new created ones. Points remain snapped.

Still not perfect, but way better :)[image: result]

It's also possible to do the same with the lines' layer

Answer (score 0):

I have used a different approach with success. Add a dummy feature in each layer you want to move, having a common point that you can easily identify after that. If you have to move multiple layers of different type, let's say Point, Line, Polygon, then create a dummy point in the point layer outside of your actual interest area, a line in the lines layer that touches the point (with snap tool) and the same with the polygon layer. After that, select all features from one layer that you have to move, plus the dummy feature. Move them to the desired position. After that, do the same with other layers, using the dummy features for snapping to the correct position. At the end, just delete all dummy features.