# Simultaneously editing 2 features from 2 different layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, editing

Is there a way in QGIS to edit 2 different features from 2 different layers at once.

For example I selected a point in a point layer and a polygon in a polygon layer and I want to move them to another place at the same time.

I can enable editing on both layer but I still have to move my features one after the other which means I can't graphically move my 2 features by exactly the same x and y. That is a problem since I want them to stay at the same place relative to each other.

I found [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/57270/155843) from 7 years ago saying it is not possible. I'm wondering if the situation has changed

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302260/how-to-edit-geometry-of-multiple-layers-simultaneously-in-qgis-3

Comment: Yes :-) That's exactly it. Thanks for the link. I feel embarassed I missed it.