# Moving all merged layers at once using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 3.10.

Following the query at [QGIS 3.10 problem with merging layers & multipart promotion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347301/qgis-3-10-problem-with-merging-layers-multipart-promotion) I merged my layers into one piece. Now I would like to make them draggable across the map, as per my previous query at [Moving layer across map canvas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346929/moving-layer-across-map-canvas).

I spotted, that despite the all-in-one performance, the draggable tool still moves only one layer selected:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to have all of them moved at the same time.

Is it possible?

---

I tried to use the " Remove duplicate geometries" option, although the result is still the same:

[image]

A similar question has been asked as [Moving two layers at once in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57270/how-can-i-move-two-layers-at-once-in-qgis) but is not applied to the merged layers.

My attribute table looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: You merged your layers into one, but not your geometries. Have you tried `dissolve` or `remove duplicate geometries`?

Comment: Dissolve isn't taken into account, as it moves my layer back into one piece. They must be merged as they stand now, but being draggable as one.

Comment: The Move Feature tool has two options: "move feature(s)" and "copy and move feature(s)". Which one are you using?

Comment: I am isung only "move features".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at your attribute table, you will see if the two polygons were actually merged. if they are merged there will only be one feature, if not, you will see multiple features. If you want to move them all, select them all before using the move feature tool. If you actually want to merge them before moving, then select them all and use the `merge selected features`tool.

Comment: How can I recognize from the data attribute tabled, that my 2 polygons have been merged? Where can I find the "Merge selected features" tool in QGIS 3.10?

Comment: if they are merged, there will only be a single feature in your attribute table, compared to 2. the merge slected features is located in the `edit` dropdown a the top left of your screen.

Comment: They appear as a single feature, but I still can't move them as one

Comment: I have updated this query, showing as my data attribute table looks like. There are 3 elements, which sources come from single layers. It's already been merged.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I managed with it.
Since our layers are merged, to make sure, that all of them are moved we must select from the main toolbar the "Select All features" option. Afterward, our merged polygons should appear as yellow. If this is so, you can use advanced digitalizing tools without a problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: that is the second part of my answer below...